# Adding custom socket-io Event types in a fastify-cli generated project

Tags: typescript, fastify

I wanted to add custom types for my fastify-socket.io events but I get a TS error of

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'io' must be of type 
'Server<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, any>', but here has type 
'Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, DefaultEventsMap, any>'.ts(2717)
```

Here is my code:

```
// apps/server-socket/src/plugins/socket-io.ts

import { ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents } from "my-types"
import fp from "fastify-plugin"
import socketioServer from "fastify-socket.io"
import { Server } from "socket.io"

export default fp(async fastify => {
  fastify.register(socketioServer, {
    cors: { origin: process.env.WEB_URL, methods: ["GET", "POST"] },
  })
})

declare module "fastify" {
  export interface FastifyInstance {
    io: Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents> // TS Error here
  }
}
```

I tried to follow this [example](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli/blob/master/templates/app-ts/src/plugins/support.ts) from fastify-cli github but still confused on what to do.